How to create a Hive table with JSON stored as parquet, AND there is a special character in one nested field
I am unable to create a table from nested JSON data that is stored as parquet and contains a hyphen "-" in one of the nested fields.
Example JSON:
{
  "level1": {
    "level-2": {
      "data": "some.string",
      "level3": {
        "level4": {
          "id": 1234,
          "counts":
            {
              "count1": 1,
              "count2": 2,
              "count3": 3
            }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

I have tried many things and read through other similar issues, but I cannot seem to find a solution to this exact problem and documentation has not been helpful.
I read one post that you can map a field with a special character in order to rename it, as I have tried below.  The error I receive is "Operation not allowed: ROW FORMAT SERDE is incompatible with format 'parquet'".
If I remove the serde lines, a table will create, but any nested values inside "level2" returns NULL.
I have tried single quotes, double quotes, back ticks and each one returns an error.  How do I overcome the "-" in the nested "level-2" field of the original data?
Simply removing "-" in the original raw data is not an option.  I am trying to find a workaround without reprocessing any of the data.
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS database.my_table (
  level1: STRUCT<
    level2: STRUCT<
      data: STRING,
      level3:  STRUCT<
        level4: STRUCT<
          id: INT,
          counts: STRUCT<
              count1: INT,
              count2: INT,
              count3: INT
            >
        >
      >
    >
  >
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe'  
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ('level2'='level-2')
STORED AS PARQUET
LOCATION '/my/parquet/data';

